# Android GPS Locating, Won't Deliver Location

Tags: android, gps, location, latitude-longitude

Goal: Determine GPS location once, then place the latitude/longitude into two separate EditText boxes to show the user.

Problem: I have tested my method and it works fine in the emulator, I send it GPS coord's and it works fine and dandy. I try it on two separate devices (v2.1 phone, v4.0 ICS tablet) and the GPS icon comes up in notifications (all good), but just stays there trying to determine location. I have tested it plenty of times and given plenty of time each time I tested. *EDIT: Works fine on phone when I go outside so I can cross this off. Tablet still having problems.*

I am in the middle of Brisbane so I doubt it's a location issue - besides, Google Maps works just fine when locating me via GPS.

If I turn the GPS off so it defaults back to Network locating, it works great and gives me the location.

The Methods:

(The method I call);

```java
public void locateCoordinates(EditText latitudeInput, EditText longitudeInput) {
    // Find coordinates, place them in EditText boxes.

    // Create the locating services if needed
    if(locManager == null) {
        locManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    }
    if(locListener != null) {
        // Unregister listener from locManager (in case of double click of Locate button)
        locManager.removeUpdates(locListener);
    }
    locListener = new LocListenerImpl(locManager, latitudeInput, longitudeInput);

    if(locManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
        locManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locListener);
    } else if(locManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) {
        locManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locListener);
        Toast.makeText(this,
                "GPS unavailable, trying network-based location instead.",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this,
                "No locating methods enabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

(Listener Implementation Class);

```java
public class LocListenerImpl implements LocationListener {

    private LocationManager locManager = null;
    private EditText latitudeInput = null;
    private EditText longitudeInput = null;

    public LocListenerImpl(LocationManager locManager, EditText latitudeInput, EditText longitudeInput) {
        this.latitudeInput = latitudeInput;
        this.longitudeInput = longitudeInput;
        this.locManager = locManager;
    }

    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        if(location != null) {
            latitudeInput.setText(String.valueOf(location.getLatitude()));
            longitudeInput.setText(String.valueOf(location.getLongitude()));
            locManager.removeUpdates(this); // Location found, unregister listener
        }
    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
}
```

I am struggling to see what I have done wrong or what might be causing this. Any help appreciated!

Comment: Are you inside a structure or in some way do not have a clear view of the sky?

Comment: I just went outside then into clear blue sky, tried it, works on my phone, but not my tablet.

My tablet is the Asus Eee Pad Transformer, so it's no cheapie

Comment: See if you can get your hands on another tablet or else, try downloading some GPS depending application on your tablet and see if it works. Your product might be defective.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting  locManager.removeUpdates(this) this in some other method like in onStop() or in else loop inside same method

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks completely OK, so there must be problem with your device..

It takes sometimes 10 minutes or so to take proper GPS lock..When you don't have internet connection, it can't download coarse data about satelites ephemerides from internet and thus it takes long time to find satelites..And that even if you have clear view on sky.

Network provider is instant on the other side, so just try to wait longer..Or try to restart your device, or try to uncheck and check location services checkbox in location settings (that helped some people who wasn't able to get GPS fix), or try to download [GPS status](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.eclipsim.gpsstatus2&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5lY2xpcHNpbS5ncHNzdGF0dXMyIl0.) app, where you can see some more specific data about GPS (last time fix, time to first fix, status of aGPS data, satellites details, ..)

Comment: Thanks, I will try that app on my Tablet and get back to you.

Comment: (I thought I clicked add comment but it doesn't seem to have gone through, so here it is again:) The GPS Status app works fine on the Tablet. Allowed it to download aGPS data, but it still didn't help my app get location.

May very well be something to do with my device..?

Comment: And the GPS status app itself gets GPS fix? It doesn't help to other app at all, but you can see there detailed information about GPS..As I've said, code looks OK, I expect it is device-related issue.

Answer (score 0):

One possible reason for the devices unable to get the location is that they are unable to connect to the satellites in absence of clear view of the sky. You are getting location via network (cell triangulation) because it only needs the carrier provider for determine the location. Google maps use a mixture of all the methods available(wi-fi, network, GPS) to locate. For testing on real device, I suggest you to go into open sky and have some fresh air :)

Comment: This worked for my phone, managed to get the GPS location very quickly. Tablet still keeps the icon there for minutes and never gets a location.

In my defence I had tried the 'go outside' idea a while ago, however it was raining heavily so perhaps that's what stopped it working then. :)